# What mathematics do I need to translate from flat coordinates to exponentially curved space? Metric tensor?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

If I have a flat cartesian space, but then introduce a local curvature (that is inverse proportional to the square of the distance) starting at the origin and extending some arbitrary amount (until it again reaches flat cartesian, i.e. not asymptotically flat), what mathematics do I need to model this? Is it the metric tensor? And is there an easy way to derive this tensor, if I have no experience with tensors whatsoever?

I'm thinking in terms of general relativity but without curvature in time. To be specific, I want a metric tensor that describes a curved geometry where a geodesic would tends toward the massive body at the center at an exponentially increasing rate.

Sorry if this question doesn't make sense to you. I'm not a mathematician and don't know what I don't know.

Comment: Yes, if you're talking about curvature, you need a metric tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a good starting point for your investigations would be to first consider the special case of *conformally Euclidean geometry* which uses the simplest type of metric tensor (and in fact can be understood without the use of any tensor terminology). This special case is also especially physically intuitive because it can be viewed through the lens of  geometrical optics (pun intended). Snell's Law of refraction explains why the geodesics bend.

Here is one very readable introduction.

**Near the Horizon: An Invitation to Geometric Optics**
Henk W. Broer
Publisher:
MAA Press
Publication Date:
2017
Number of Pages:
178
Format:
Hardcover
Series:
Carus Mathematical Monographs 33

> This new book in the MAA’s Carus Mathematical Monograph series uses
> the investigation of the propagation of the sun’s light near the
> horizon as the inspiration for studying light rays as geodesics.